# Daemon that monitors a 'queue' and runs commands, asynchronously

Tags: php, asynchronous, parallel-processing, rabbitmq

I know this has been asked before, but I can't figure out a particular piece of the puzzle and would really like any help on this!

**Program Flow :**

*INITIAL REQUEST :* Browser  -> Apache  -> to PHP -> PHP sends taskinfo about a time consuming command,  to 'something', and returns instantly.

There could be multiple requests being sent at the same time to the server, by multiple browsers.

*SERVER:* The 'something' runs a specific command with the taskinfo as params PARALLELY in the BACKGROUND > saves output to DB

*AJAX:* -> Apache -> PHP -> Checks DB -> Returns info to user.

I have explored solutions such as rabbitmq / gearman etc, but am unable to figure them out.

The **precise problem** is that I can't figure out the part where the  'something' (a daemon), automatically runs the specified command, whenever a task in added to a 'queue/list'. The way I see it, a command needs to run seperate from the daemon, and I don't understand where or how this command should run.

So in short: A non-blocking daemon that monitors a queue and runs a specific command!

But How  ?

Been stuck at this for a few days now. I know there are simpler alternatives like curl and exec(), but they are not suitable for my use case.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on what you use to create the daemon, it should be rather straight-forward. An event loop is used to let you react on the incoming tasks socket. You queue the task. While there are tasks, you register a callback to execute it. Upon executing the task, fetch the next one from queue etc. It should be rather easy to do this using library such as [icicle](https://icicle.io/)

Comment: oh by 'daemon' I meant something like rabbitmq beanstald server that probably just runs at startup. Thanks for icicle, checking it out..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the second tutorial for rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html), looks a lot like what you need. If it's not clear, take a look at the first one first - it's quite simple.

Basically any subscribing client to rabbitmq broker can be *your daemon*  and you can have as many of them as you want (*in general*).

Comment: Do you mean I can/should  run `worker.sh` as a background daemon, using some startup script (instead of trying to link it with the rabbitmq-server)  ? If so I'll be manually managing the number of workers there are at any given moment ? ty

Comment: What do you mean by link it with RMQ? Worker is a subscribing client to RMQ. Yes you should autostart and manually manage the number of workers, RMQ doesn't do this.

Comment: link with RMQ: I thought I could just tell a specific queue what specific command to run..., but anyways now I know atleast what this thing does do, sort of. thanks

Comment: Queue is just a buffer that the broker uses to store messages, and the subscriber to "pull" from it. The subscriber(which is a process) can do things when it receives a message. I suggest going through first tutorial, and then the second one, it will be clearer. And you are welcome.